# how to find image manifest of Fluentd docker image for AWS ecr put-image

Tags: docker-registry, amazon-ecr

Team,
I am trying to upload Fluentd image to AWS ecr and getting error.
I have below images and tagged.

```
docker images | grep fluent
123.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sre-tools/fluentd-ds   latest                             b285a4690f19        5 months ago        209MB
123.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sre-tools/fluentd-ds   v1.8                               b285a4690f19        5 months ago        209MB
fluentd                                                             v1.8-debian-1                      b285a4690f19        5 months ago        209MB
```

```
aws ecr put-image  --repository-name sre-tools/fluentd-ds:v1.8
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --image-manifest is required
```

from where should I get the image manifest? sorry this is my first time.

is manifest the sha256 of image? if yes I tried below

```
 docker inspect  b285a4690f19 | grep sha -i
        "Id": "sha256:b285a4690f19ea48e817d0654df9d9225abb9c8ddb2fd3ffb9c1e00b3d7189ac",
            "fluentd@sha256:a25d9ebbb344c40e1e84c173a466bc1f6e77a0233567fe778db1c6ffdeccf2e8"
                "RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=d5d6da717fd48524596f9b78ac5a2eeb9691753da5c06923a6c31190abe01a62",
            "Image": "sha256:66dc2c47c50cdf7f75ec68d1d027b4f139c4e5afcb2e0229ded10c659feafc43",
                "RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=d5d6da717fd48524596f9b78ac5a2eeb9691753da5c06923a6c31190abe01a62",
            "Image": "sha256:66dc2c47c50cdf7f75ec68d1d027b4f139c4e5afcb2e0229ded10c659feafc43",
                "sha256:488dfecc21b1bc607e09368d2791cb784cf8c4ec5c05d2952b045b3e0f8cc01e",
                "sha256:6bab58ebc554a7f95a80ee2dca3fbb05e05a5bceadab8b6d99d9eb41e0c7532f",
```

```
aws ecr put-image  --repository-name sre-tools/fluentd-ds --image-manifest "sha256:a25d9ebbb344c40e1e84c173a466bc1f6e77a0233567fe778db1c6ffdeccf2e8"

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutImage operation: Invalid parameter at 'ImageManifest' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid JSON syntax'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to provide a json file and not direct input

```
aws ecr put-image  --repository-name sre-tools/fluentd-ds --image-manifest manifest.json"
```

also, got a workaround by using docker cli instead

```
docker push sre-tools/fluentd-ds:v1
```